# On dual-boot iMac, after fixing "EFI Boot" issue, will booting Windows cause the same issue again?

Tags: windows-xp, partitioning, multi-boot, mac, efi

On my dual-boot iMac, after fixing the well-known "EFI Boot" issue, will booting Windows cause the same issue again?

I'm hesitant to try booting Windows until I hear from others.

Details:

It all started when I had been working in Windows and then re-booted into Mac OSX Snow Leopard.  Any attempt to boot into OSX would result in two giveaway symptoms:
1) The MAC HD was re-named "EFI Boot", and 
2) a gray progress bar stopped at 10% and the spinning wheel kept spinning - no joy.

Many articles on Mac Forums describe the same thing, including the fix, which is to erasing the damaged partition and either:
a) re-install the OS from DVD, or
b) perform a Time Machine RESTORE (which I did).

Is there anything I can do to keep enjoying the benefits of a dual-boot iMac without fear of a repeat problem and associated 2-hour restore from Time Machine?

Comment: Did you use Boot Camp to install Windows, or is this a rEFIt rig?

Answer (score 0):

From my logical but not practical understanding, no it shouldn't happen. Boot camp makes a hybrid partition file, Windows sees a MBR as it wants, and Mac sees something it can move if it wants to. You may need to rebless your hard drive (or the mac partition), to make it bootable.

Did you do anything non-standard in the installation, like not use boot camp?